# Calculate VWAP by Date (Help Running Script Please)

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the script given in an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987802/python-calculate-vwap-by-date/74721528#74721528) and could really use some help figuring it out.

I'm pretty new to all this but managed to install python, pip, and the requests and pandas modules.

I am able to run the script and it outputs data; however, how do I run the script for a specific ticker and date?

For example, how do I run the script for the ticker "SPY" for the date 12/06/2022?

Thank you in advance!!!

I'm choosing the ticker "SPY" and run the script and it outputs:

```
python3 vwap.py SPY         
                        Open     High      Low    Close    volume        Date          vwap
Time                                                                                       
2022-12-07 06:46:00  16975.0  16975.1  16975.0  16975.1  0.091722  2022-12-07  16975.066667
2022-12-07 06:47:00  16975.1  16975.1  16970.1  16970.1  0.356965  2022-12-07  16972.441261
2022-12-07 06:48:00  16970.1  16970.2  16970.1  16970.2  0.506126  2022-12-07  16971.235547
2022-12-07 06:49:00  16970.1  16970.2  16970.1  16970.2  0.019041  2022-12-07  16971.214648
2022-12-07 06:50:00  16970.2  16970.2  16955.4  16957.5  3.832814  2022-12-07  16963.096116
...                      ...      ...      ...      ...       ...         ...           ...
2022-12-07 18:41:00  16804.4  16804.4  16804.4  16804.4  0.471748  2022-12-07  16812.490887
2022-12-07 18:42:00  16804.4  16810.4  16804.4  16807.3  6.735564  2022-12-07  16812.464360
2022-12-07 18:43:00  16808.7  16812.1  16805.5  16805.5  3.790436  2022-12-07  16812.450520
2022-12-07 18:44:00  16805.6  16808.7  16803.0  16803.0  0.827792  2022-12-07  16812.445734
2022-12-07 18:45:00  16803.0  16803.0  16803.0  16803.0  0.000000  2022-12-07  16812.445734

[720 rows x 7 columns]
```

However, if I run the script and don't type a ticker it gives me the same output. So how do I run the script for a specific ticker and date?

Comment: You, you have added code to pass in a ticker symbol, right?  So you know how to handle command line arguments?  The date can just be another argument.

Comment: No. The specific script I copy/pasted into a .py file didn't mention additional code. Have any ideas how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I went into the file and noticed it's using pair "XXBTZUSD" and it's pulling from a Kraken API which is most likely only crypto.

Any ideas on another API I can use that will pull stock tickers instead of crypto pairs?

Comment: Check Yahoo Finance, https://finance.yahoo.com, but this is now off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm looking to work this script for stocks instead of crypto. I know I can go to Yahoo! Finance to see typical data. You can do that almost anywhere, but I'm trying to use this script so that I can automate the vwap for any stock on any given date instead of having to look stuff up, like on Yahoo! Finance, see how much a stock traded on a given day, then pull up a chart elsewhere to look at the vwap throughout the day then multiplying the volume by the vwap price.

Comment: Yahoo Finance has an API that you can access from your script.